# React Native Reanimated

Tags: react, react-native

Ao instalar o react-native-reanimated e iniciar o aplicativo é gerado esse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procurando um pouco na internet encontrei esse tópico [Link](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-reanimated/issues/207)

Seguindo as informações seria necessário apenas fazer o seguinte comando no CMD/PowerShell porém ao executar apresenta o segundo erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verificando o package.json realmente eu não tenho essa importação nas dependencies, não sei exatamente o que devo adicionar aqui

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Se eu for na pasta node_modules eu encontro o pacote react-native-reanimated instalado, a última imagem é o arquivo package.json dentro da pasta do react-native-reanimated

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para evitar esse tipo de problema sempre instale como administrador. Dessa forma ele adiciona todas as informações automaticamente

Answer (score 0):

Foi necessário adicionar no arquivo package.json principal a dependência do react-native-reanimated manualmente

```
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
```

Após isso reiniciando a máquina e utilizando os comandos

```
npm cache clean --force
react-native run-android
```

O projeto iniciou sem o erro antes descrito